# python 3 discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

lib.py:

```
def getPlayerId(playername):

    params = {"action": "autocompleteList",
              "iso": iso,
              "server": server
             }
    rq1 = requests.post(url_base, params)
    server_data = rq1.json()
    player_data = server_data["player"]

    for player in player_data:
        if playername in player["pseudo"]:
            return player["id"]
    return 0

print(getPlayerId('JD')) # print exactly user ID
```

bot.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from lib import *

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def find(ctx, *args):
    ...
    player_id = getPlayerId('JD')` # return 0 even though the user exists
    ...
```

My problem is that when I call `getPlayerId` in bot command it always get 0, although `getPlayerId` run properly (return ID of player) if I call it at lib.py
I don't know what is the problem with my code since it doesn't show any error. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: If you change your function to print `server_data`, it it getting what you expect when called by your other code?

Comment: when I call this function alone, everything runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getPlayerId(playername):
player_id = 0;
params = {"action": "autocompleteList",
          "iso": iso,
          "server": server
         }
rq1 = requests.post(url_base, params)
server_data = rq1.json()
player_data = server_data["player"]

for player in player_data:
    if playername in player["pseudo"]:
        player_id = player["id"]
return player_id
```

Comment: Thank you but I've tried this way but it still the same result, get 0 returned.